# Convert results of Request() to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
request('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Gamma Case', function (e, r, body){
    var req_data = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(req_data); 
    });
```

It returns me 
`{ success: true,
  lowest_price: '$0.03',
  volume: '30,502',
  median_price: '$0.01' }`

How can I do for convert the lowest_price into a variable? I tryed:

```
 var results = req_data.map(function(item){
 return {lowest_price : item["lowest_price"]};
 });
 console.log(results);
```

But its says that .req_data.map is not a function.

Thank you!

Comment: use  var lowPrice = req_data['lowest_price']

Comment: You are awesome, add it as an answer so I vote you like the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
request('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Gamma Case', function (e, r, body){
    return {lowest_price: JSON.parse(body).lowest_price};
    });
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much. But how can I do for turn the return into a variable?

Comment: @MatiasRodriguez No problem. Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you. What do you mean? You can set a variable like this: `var lowest_price = JSON.parse(body).lowest_price;` inside the request. If you want to set it outside, you can declare en empty variable `var lowest_price;` outside and set it inside the request like this: `lowest_price = JSON.parse(body).lowest_price;`

Answer (score 0):

`req_data` is an object, not an array, so you can't use `map` on it. Just do `return {lowest_price : req_data["lowest_price"]};`.